# Is there a way to get 32 bit (float) values out of Math.sin() or a similar class, maybe smth like Math.sin(float a)

Tags: java, math, floating-point, gpu, aparapi

I am experimenting with using my GPU in java, I am using Aparapi but I have an issue where if I use (float)Math.sin(x) it still falls back to the CPU because my GPU doesn't support F64. is there a Math library for floats? should I be using the gpu to calculate sins at all?

Comment: Try using Java 32-bit. Just be wary that operations on ```long``` and ```double``` are not thread-safe.

Comment: @MireaRadu Java 32-bit has nothing to do with the size of double. All types in Java are the same regardless of architectures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect a project like this to come with math routines of its own so that you can call functions implemented on the GPU.

And it does: `Kernel.sin(float)` in Aparapi should [map to a call to the OpenCL sin function](https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi/blob/master/com.amd.aparapi/src/java/com/amd/aparapi/Kernel.java#L1737).

Whether it makes sense to do trig on the GPU, that's for you to evaluate.